# Android app crashes on playing sound

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm developing a free alphabet application but I'm not a Java developer. I've made an HTML page where there are about 150 `.png` pictures and `.mp3` sound file pairs. For example, `apple.png` and `apple.mp3` would be a pair, and there are going to be more.

I'm using webview to display the webpage with pictures and to know when the user is trying to hear the sound. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
index.html:
    ...<a href="mp3/apple.mp3"><img src="apple.png"></a>...

alphabetActivity.java:
    ...public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.endsWith(".mp3")){
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(url));
        Toast.makeText(HelloWebviewActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mediaPlayer.start();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(HelloWebviewActivity.this, "not mp3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
}...
```

All sounds are stored at `assets/www/mp3`.

.

But there is a problem: every time I click on a picture, my application crashes with a `Forced close...` message. Is there any way to make it work?

### Found my own solution for this problem.

I've copied all the sounds to res/raw folder, changed links in index.html from "mp3/apple.mp3" to "apple" and used this code:

```
if(mPlayer!=null){
   mPlayer.stop();
   mPlayer.release();}
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(url.substring(26), "raw", getPackageName());;
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), id);
mPlayer.start();
```

Right now this code is working. Thanks for help =)

Comment: Do you get anything on logcat? And just a comment, you need to release a mediaplayer after you use it, otherwise the internal mixer will get full after the user tries to play a few audio files.

Comment: You should post the exception from logcat, here is how to get it:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: It is not shocking to abnswer your own question rather than editing the question and never validating an answer.

Comment: rds, I didn't know about that feature, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own solution for this problem.

I've copied all the sounds to res/raw folder, changed links in index.html from "mp3/apple.mp3" to "apple" and used this code:

```
if(mPlayer!=null){
   mPlayer.stop();
   mPlayer.release();}
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(url.substring(26), "raw", getPackageName());;
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), id);
mPlayer.start();
```

Right now this code is working. Thanks for help =)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `MediaPlayer.create()` is synchronous.Thus it blocks the UI thred in the place of invocation, creating ANR = Application Not Responsive error. To fix that you need to use asynchronous `MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` calls. For details see: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

More precisely, instead of:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(url));
```

you should do something similar to:

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(url));
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                });
```